# Get predecessor key from map using java

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I have a map in this

```
    TreeMap<Integer, Float> matrixMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Float>();
```

Results in

```
{12=0.4, 24=0.63, 36=0.86, 48=1.12, 60=1.39, 72=1.67, 84=1.98, 96=2.31, 108=3.3, 120=3.84, 132=4.4, 144=5.0, 156=5.62, 168=6.28, 180=6.97, 192=7.34, 
204=7.74, 216=8.15, 228=8.07, 240=8.33}
```

Now, I want fetch a value of a key 25. Ideally 25 is not available in the result. So, I want to get values of 24 & 36.

```
duration  = 25
```

I'm able to get the value of 36, but how can I get the predecessor of 36.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry : matrixMap.entrySet()) {
    if(duration  < entry.getKey())
    {
        max = entry.getValue();
        break;
    }

}
```

How to get immediate predecessor value too(24 key in this case)?

Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of the first key >= 25:

```
matrixMap.tailMap(25).values().next()
```

or:

```
matrixMap.get(matrixMap.tailMap(25).firstKey())
```

To get the value of the first key <= 25:

```
matrixMap.get(matrixMap.headMap(25).lastKey())
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using the following way.

```
int above = matrixMap.ceilingKey(duration);
int below = matrixMap.floorKey(duration);
logger.info("above="+above+", below="+below);
min = insuranceMatrixMap.get(below);
max = insuranceMatrixMap.get(above);
```